# Is it possible to make Spring @Import or @Configuration parametrized?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-boot

I've created a lot of common small bean-definition containers (`@Configuration`) which I use to rapidly develop applications with Spring Boot like:

```
@Import({
   FreemarkerViewResolver.class, // registers freemarker that auto appends <#escape etc.
   ConfigurationFromPropertiesFile.class, // loads conf/configuration.properties
   UtfContentTypeResponse.class, // sets proper Content-language and Content-type
   LocaleResolverWithLanguageSwitchController // Locale resolver + switch controller
 );
 class MySpringBootApp ...
```

For example, one of such `@Configuration`s can set up session storage for locale cookie with web controller to switch to selected language etc.

They are very fun to work with and reuse, but it would be really great to make it **parametrized**, which could allow lot more reusege. I mean something like:

**Pseudo code**:

```
@Imports( imports = {
  @FreemarkerViewResolver( escapeHtml = true, autoIncludeSpringMacros = true),
  @ConfigurationFromProperties( path = "conf/configuration.properties" ),
  @ContentTypeResponse( encoding = "UTF-8" ),
  @LocaleResolver( switchLocaleUrl = "/locale/{loc}", defaultLocale = "en"
})
```

So, I basically mean "configurable `@Configurations`". **What would be the best way to make the configuration that way?**

Maybe something more like this (again, pseudo code):

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    public FreemarkerConfiguration freemarkerConfiguration() {
       return FreemarkerConfigurationBuilder.withEscpeAutoAppend();
    }

    @Configuration
    public ConfigurationFromPropertiesFile conf() {
       return ConfigurationFromPropertiesFile.fromPath("...");
    }

    @Configuration
    public LocaleResolverConfigurator loc() {
       return LocaleResolverConfigurator.trackedInCookie().withDefaultLocale("en").withSwitchUrl("/switchlocale/{loc}");
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let me quote [Spring Boot Reference Guide - Externalized Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

*"Spring Boot allows you to externalize your configuration so you can work with the same application code in different environments."*

In my opinion the customization is not done at import time via annotation parameters like in your 2nd pseudo code block, instead the customization happens at run time e.g. in the configuration classes. Let me adapt your 3rd code block (only one function):

```java
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    // Provide a default implementation for FreeMarkerConfigurer only
    // if the user of our config doesn't define her own configurer.
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(FreeMarkerConfigurer.class)
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer result = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        result.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/views/");
        return result;
    }

    ...

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolverConfigurator loc() {
        String defaultLocale = env.getProperty("my.app.config.defaultlocale", "en");
        String switchLocale = env.getProperty("my.app.config.switchlocale", "/switchlocale/{loc}");

        return LocaleResolverConfigurator.trackedInCookie().withDefaultLocale(defaultLocale).withSwitchUrl(switchLocale);
    }
```

For `LocaleResolverConfigurator` the configuration is read from the environment, meaningful default values are defined. It is easy to change the default value(s) by providing a different value for a config parameter in any of the supported ways (documented in the first link) - via command line or a yaml file. The advantage over annotation parameters is that you can change the behavior at run time instead of compile time.

You could also inject the config parameters (if you prefer to have them as instance variable) or use a lot of other conditions, e.g. [`@ConditionalOnMissingBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html), [`@ConditionalOnClass`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnClass.html), [`@ConditionalOnExpression`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnExpression.html) and [so on](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/package-frame.html). For example with `@ConditionalOnClass` you could check if a particular class is on your class path and provide a setting for the library identified by this class. With `@ConditionalOnMissingClass` you could provide an alternative implementation. In the example above I used `ConditionalOnMissingBean` to provide a default implementation for the `FreeMarkerConfigurer`. This implementation is only used when no `FreeMarkerConfigurer` bean is available thus can be overridden easily.

Take a look at the starters provided by Spring Boot or the community. A good read is also this [blog entry](http://geowarin.github.io/understanding-spring-boot.html). I learned a lot from [spring-boot-starter-batch-web](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-starter-batch-web), they had an article series in a German Java magazine, but parts are also online, see [Boot your own infrastructure – Extending Spring Boot in five steps](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/11/extending-spring-boot-five-steps-writing-spring-boot-starter/) (**MUST READ**) and especially the paragraph "Make your starter configurable by using properties".

Comment: Are you sure the method annotation should be a `@Configuration`? Also, I very dislike the properties-driven config, as most of my configuration is not environment-dependent and also this drive to a huge bag of all the properties mixed together.

Comment: @PiotrMüller You should probably mention your dislike of properties in the question as it changes what a good answer is quite considerably. One very easy way to get more structure in the configuration file is to use YAML. If you also don't like YAML then you should mention that too.

Comment: 1) For the `@Configuration` annotation: I just took your code and adopted it to the "properties-driven config". 2) You can use properties even for config data which is not environment-dependent. All the settings in your 2nd code block are ideal to be configured in properties. 3) There are a lot of other possibilities beside properties. I updated my answer with a scenario for `@ConditionalOnClass` and a link to a blog entry.

Comment: @ChrLipp I am asking for annotation because I don't even know if `@Configuration` is allowed at method level - my code was just a pseudo code. Does `LocaleResolverConfigurator ` will be handled as regular `@Configuration` class and all methods containing the `@Bean`s will create a beans?

Comment: OK, I see. I did miss that one. I don't think that this is possible and I am not quite sure why you would need that. You have multiple configs and you have to import them as you did before - the only change would you can parametrize the config. To get rid of the imports you could also define your own `Enable*`  annotation and you could also group multiple configs in a single `Enable*`  annotation.

Comment: The most imporant problem with configuring by properties is that you have switches for X, Y, Z and you are restricted by them. This restrict how elastic your components are - if I would have programmatic config, I could **inject implementations** like "strategy patterns" for `@Configurations` that require them. Like `FreemarkerResolver` with `List` of `EscapingInterceptor` `IncludeSpringMacrosInterceptor` etc. - it is a lot better than switches in properties, because of infinite possibilities. I know I can give class name by properties and dynamically instantiate but I don't consider it clean.

Comment: You respond only to the properties, but not the other mechanism provided by Spring Boot. For your last comment you can define a bean for a standard implementation shielded with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`. If anyone wants another implementation she is free to provide a bean with the same name and this bean is taken. So you can inject any implementation just as you want. Did you read the blog entry and the "must read" from the last paragraph? I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

Though I like the idea of having imports be parameterized, I think that as it stands now using `@Import` and `@Configuration` not a good fit.

I can think of two ways to use dynamic configurations, that don't rely on `PropertySource` style configuration.

1. Create a custom `@ImportConfig` annotation and annotation processor that accepts configuration properties that are hard-coded into the generated source files.
2. Use a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` or `BeanPostProcessor` to add or manipulate your included beans respectively.

Neither is particularly simple IMO, but since it looks like you have a particular way of working. So it could be worth the time invested.